# how to print the day of the month(mon,tue) after the date entered by user using Shell Scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

This Does not work

```
echo " ENter Day Month Year "
read day
read month
read year
cal $month $year
echo "`date --date '$year-$month-$day' +%A`"
```

However, this works

```
date --date '2018-11-02' +%A
```

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date --date "$year-$month-$day" +%A
```